# QUnit Newbie, working with Wordpad Text File

Tags: qunit

I'm developing a Javascript app with Wordpad [forced to].  When my test passes within the browser that houses qunit code, do I move the successful code to an alternate location?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your scenario correctly

Lets say the code that is going to be tested is placed myProject.js, and your tests are placed in myTests.js

You don't need to move the code to alternate location (after successful tests), you can just edit myTests.js to keep the tests for failed javascript code Or add new test cases (depending upon your requirement)